# Asp.net MVC action not reached after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I had an action rendered inside Razer view like below:

```
<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar uk-dropdown-width-4">
                        @(Html.Action("QuickSearch", "Trip", new { Area = "BackOffice" ))

</div>
```

At the first call it works fine, but once any form submitted and the post action returns view the QuickSearch action didn't reach and the view hangs for long time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Html.Action instead of @(Html.Action

Comment: @YatFeiLeong Thanks for your replay, but It didn't help the same issue still appears.

Comment: r u using .net Core, .net6 or MVC5?

Comment: @YatFeiLeong MVC5

Comment: @YatFeiLeong finally I found the reason but I could not figure out why this happened, I had two forms inside the same view and the user click submit button of the second form the first form always submitted.

Comment: Haha..  Html.action is rendering sub form.  It surely submit everything as long as user click submit button.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong Html.action is rendering another form, not nested form. but It submitted once click submit button inside other form.

Comment: I know, unless you are using Ajax, Sub form and main form will be posted together. That is how it works.

Comment: @YatFeiLeong I got around this issue by remove the first form and do post action using js ajax call

Comment: you may put your own answer in the post to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this issue and I would like to share it here.

I just removed the first form tag and do post action using JS ajax call, also I changed the button type from 'submit' to 'button'.

Hope this will be useful for others.